# How can I detect when the user is X seconds from the end of a video?

Tags: jquery, video

I need to detect when a video is 30 seconds from the end of the total. For example, if my video is 1m35s in length, I want to trigger an event when it reaches 1m05s.

**UPDATE**

I have worked out how to trigger an event at any point over 30 seconds from the end, i.e 30s, 29s, 28s and so on. The problem is, the code below trigger repeatedly each second, but I only want this event to occur once, wether it happens at -30s, -22s or -15s.

```
var video = $('#video');

function func() {
    if ( video[0].currentTime > video[0].duration-30 ) {
        console.log('You are less than 30 seconds from the end!');
    }
}

video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    func();
});
```

Comment: FYI, `bind` is deprecated in the current version of jQuery. You might use `on` since you're writing new code.

Comment: Try :  `if ( video[0].currentTime == video[0].duration-30 )`. Alternatively just close the timer when the target time is reached with `video[0].currentTime >= video[0].duration-30`. I can show, if you need it.

Comment: @VC.One yes please, could you add an answer please? I can then mark as correct if it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use a end of file event boolean variable - eofevent.

Logic : reset this variable when ever you start your playback. Use it as a flag , once triggered , don't call the func() again.

```
var video = $('#video');
var eofevent = false; 


function func() {
    if ( video[0].currentTime > video[0].duration-30 ) {
        console.log('You are less than 30 seconds from the end!');
        eofevent = true;
    }
}

video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    if( eofevent == false )
       func();
});

video.on('play', function() {
     if ( video[0].currentTime < video[0].duration ) {
        console.log('on Playing Reset!');
        eofevent = false;
    }
});

video.on('playing', function() {
    if ( video[0].currentTime < video[0].duration ) {
        console.log('on Playing Reset!');
        eofevent = false;
    }
});
```

Note: I am not a jquery /javascript coder , any syntax mistake please excuse.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to unbind the `timeupdate` event once you reach your goal:

```js
var video = $('#video');

function func() {
    if ( video[0].currentTime > video[0].duration-30 ) {
        console.log('You are less than 30 seconds from the end!');
        video.off('timeupdate'); // <--
    }
}

video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    func();
});
```

(I have not tested the code)

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately I don’t think this approach is viable for me,  as I’m using timeupdate for other events. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: First, have a look at the documentation for `off()`, you can also unbind a given handle and leave the rest in place. Alternatively, you can add a global variable (or closure, or whatever method you prefer) and use it to keep track of whether the message has already been sent.